# bootstrap textbox class "form-control" wont change in size

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying to create a form while using the bootstrap theme, but when I'd add the class="form-control" over an asp:textbox it seems to lock the size of the textbox to a fairly small size. Even if i'd put a style="width:500px" or whatever number, the size doesn't change at all.

Is there a reason that they're locked to a specific size? if so, I'm unsure where in the bootstrap is responsible for that.

<-------------EDIT-------------------------->

```
 <div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Submit Idea</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
     <table border="0" class="nav-justified">
          <tr>
              <td style="width: 185px">
      <label for="inputTitle" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Title:</label></td>
              <td style="width: 149px"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator controltovalidate="inputTitle" ID="TitleValidator0" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Title is required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>      
              </td>
              <td>      
          <asp:TextBox class="form-control"  style="width:1000px;" ID="inputTitle" runat="server" placeholder="Title"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: There might be multiple reasons for that (a container with a fixed width size, for example). Please provide some code we can deal with, otherwise will be impossible to know what is exactly going wrong. Welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: @DavideVitali Sorry for not adding code, I've added some now. So my code is within a table within a panel because I was trying to organize it in a specific way. But even when the code wasn't within a table and was in a jumbotron rather than a panel, it still did the same thing, the width is set to 1000 just because I was trying to get it to be really big to see if it resizes.

Comment: As of version 4, Bootstrap has dropped the `panel` component... [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/#panels)

Comment: @DavideVitali I am using bootstrap 3 but it didn't let me use that in the tags. I'm using a visual-studio template webform project so it comes with a default bootstrap 3

Comment: I suggest you start from scratch with the latest version... a template with an outdated version? No way!

Comment: @DavideVitali I made the project last week, and I've got too much done to start it over.

Comment: @DavideVitali I tried making a new one after fully updating my visual studio, and the bootstrap that comes with it is version 3.3.7

Comment: You’ll have to manually upgrade selecting “nuget manager” and then upgrading the already installed bootstrap

Comment: @DavideVitali When I try that and use a bootstrap 4 navbar, it vanished and doesn't display it

Comment: @zadders: can you post the generated HTML? With the webform tags like `<asp:TextBox>`, we can't reproduce the error. Also double check if you've installed the Bootstrap correctly.

Comment: Use Inspect element feature to find out which property is causing the fixed size...i believe there might be max width used somewhere...just remove that